# Translations for SonarQube Platform

Tags: sonarqube, translation, sonarqube-web

I have installed the plug-in *French Pack*, but when I restart the SonarQube server, I have no changes, my SonarQube is always in English. 
[image]

How passing all my SonarQube in French ?

If I create my own SonarQube widget, if I use the plug-in *French Pack*, automatically the widget is translate or not ?? If not how to do to translate a widget ???

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've chosen French localization in your browser, what you're (not) seeing is a product of the fact that the [French localization pack](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-l10n-fr) hasn't been released in a very long time.

To answer the second part of your question, it is possible to localize a plugin by providing the correct localization files, e.g. `org/sonar/l10n/mysonarplugin_fr.properties`. That's documented [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Internationalization#Internationalization-LocalizingaPlugin).